# How can I create multipolygon using shapely?

Tags: python, geometry, shapely, multi-polygon

I am going to create polygon, but it produce invalid polygon form this data:

```
[[  0 438]
 [  0 428]
 [  0 427]
 [  6 428]
 [  9 434]
 [ 11 439]
 [  7 443]
 [  3 446]
 [  0 448]
 [  0 452]
 [  0 452]
 [  0 449]]
```

Now I want to create multipolygon from the above data. How can I create multipolygon?

Comment: In what way is it invalid? Could you add the code you are using to create it?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly what you want to do this is how I did it,

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon

lat_point_list = [0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 11, 7, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0]
lon_point_list = [438, 428, 427, 428, 434, 439, 443, 446, 448, 452, 452, 449]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
multipolygon_geom = MultiPolygon([polygon_geom])
```